# How to include typescript types for a library that does not exist in npm @types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ok so im very new to Typescript and I can't seem to figure this one out.
In my React app, I have many types dependencies like so

```
"@types/react": "^16.0.22".
```

Everything works great.

However I need to bring in a library that does not have it's types in '@types' lib on npm.

I am trying to include library *react-responsive-carousel* component, which actually has a bundled 'index.d.ts' file in the main folder already. But does not have a corresponding npm @types version.

I am trying to use the component like so:

```
<Carousel centerMode={true} centerSlidePercentage={50}>
```

But the TS comiler keeps giving me errors because it's not reading the types.

*Property 'centerMode' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & ...'.*

So how do I tell my TS compiler (typescript@2.7) to look for the d.ts file in the main directory, and not the @types directory ??

Thanks for helping thisTS noob out :)

Comment: Typescript should do this automatically, unless something is getting in the way. But if the types weren't picked up, I would expect a "cannot find declaration file for module <somename>" error on your import, rather than an error when using it. Is there such an error? If not it might be the definitions included in the package are outdated.

Comment: It is likely that the definition is already read. You would get `any` type if the library does not have typings available.

What you see is likely the result of some coding/typings error.

Comment: well you were right CRice, after looking closer at the d.ts file, I noticed centerMode and centerSlidePercentage were missing from the interface. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!